# Scrapy is not able to download the images from a URL

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline, scrapy-shell

I am using scrapy to download the images but it is not working. I get the URL in desired folder but not the images.

Here is my items.py:

```
class Brand(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    brand_image = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scraper.items import Brand


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brandDetails"

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('brands.json') as data_file:
            data_item = json.load(data_file)
        urls = list()
        for item in data_item:
            urls.append(item["url"])
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Brand()
        name = response.css("div.th::text").extract_first()
        name = name.replace('Products of ', '')
        item['name'] = name
        item['url'] = response.url
        urls = response.css("div.productimage img::attr(src)").extract_first()
        urls = "http://ozhat-turkiye.com" + urls
        item['image_urls'] = urls
        yield item
```

Here is the setting code:

```
BOT_NAME = 'scraper'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scraper.spiders'
IMAGE_STORE = 'C:/Users/SHAHRUKH/Desktop/AI'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
  'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1
}
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
```

Here is the output of my program:

```
 {'image_urls': 'http://ozhat-turkiye.com/get.aspx?id=1882267',
 'name': ' Camille Bauer',
 'url': 'http://ozhat-turkiye.com/en/camille-bauer/'}
```

Comment: I suggest you use `yield Request(url)` to download image and then save to a file instead of using Image Pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You can down those images and store it using urllib.

```
import urllib     

urllib.urlretrieve(img_url, filename)
```

For example code check [here](https://github.com/vj-09/Web-scraping/blob/master/flikr_final.py).

Comment: is there a way to check javascript error by using selenium python scrapy?

Comment: basically i have a selenium code which click on the next button of pagination and pagination data is comming from javascript function but after some time selenum click function doesn't work for me and stay on the same page is there any other way click on a button in scrapy python?

Comment: Thing is pagination can be handled without using selenium itself, no need for clicking it.There will be some pattern in the url that changes which corresponds to the different pages, for example : abcd.com/productlist/page=1/someid so u can hard code the number of pages to be crawled or take the page count and feed it and in the above example same is implemented.

Comment: yes i know but in this case pagination next page button have a javascript function in href attribute thats why i need selenium but selenium is not consistently working

Comment: if so you can use request module in python.

Comment: can you please provide some detail how to use request module in scrapy

Comment: Find how req and response is happening(https://www.getpostman.com/apps -this can be used)after knowing that we can generate the req and get the response

Comment: is there no any way to submit a form simple by using scrapy scrapy.FormRequest.from_response???